# How to create woocommerce order in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create one plugin for crowdfunding site on wordpress.
On my site i have different projects (products) and users can donate money. They can choose how much they want to donate. Now i need to create orders from my plugin for some project. I found this code

```
function create_vip_order() {

    global $woocommerce;

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => '111Joe',
        'last_name'  => 'Conlin',
        'company'    => 'Speed Society',
        'email'      => 'joe@testing.com',
        'phone'      => '760-555-1212',
        'address_1'  => '123 Main st.',
        'address_2'  => '104',
        'city'       => 'San Diego',
        'state'      => 'Ca',
        'postcode'   => '92121',
        'country'    => 'US',
    );

    // Now we create the order
    $order = wc_create_order();

    // The add_product() function below is located in
    // /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
    // This is an existing SIMPLE product
    $order->add_product( wc_get_product( '5617' ), 100 );

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );

    $order->calculate_totals();

    $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);

  }

  add_action( 'init', 'create_vip_order' );
```

and all works good , but i need to insert also value that user want to donate.

Now this script insert only adress and total 0,00

Please help me to solve this problem.

i did:

```
$test = 30000;
$order-> ->set_total($test, 'order_discount');
```

but this didnt helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use this code to set price to product and after it to create an order
    global $woocommerce;

```
  $product_id = '5617'; // a product ID or a variation ID
  $new_product_price = $_POST['amount']; // the new product price  <==== <==== <====
  $quantity = 1; // The line item quantity

  ## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  ##

  // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
  $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

  // Change the product price
  $product->set_price( $new_product_price );

  ## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  ##

  // Create the order
  $order = wc_create_order();

  // Add the product to the order
  $order->add_product( $product, $quantity);

  ## You will need to add customer data, tax line item … ##

  $order->calculate_totals(); // updating totals

  $order->save(); // Save the order data
```